# How can I convert Any to Date in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, ios11, swift4

I am receiving an date from server:

```
// It comes from server as Any let.
let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]

let userInfoDic = userInfo as NSDictionary
userInfoDic.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.date") as Any

// prints Optional(2018-04-26)
```

If I try convert to date, throws the error:

> ‘Any?’ is not convertible to 'Date'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

When I force, returns an *fatal error*.

Comment: Have you tried a DateFormatter()?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if let dateString = userInfoDic.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.date") as? String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        print(date)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, just use `userInfo["gcm.notification.date"]`. Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Also, you have to set the formatter locale to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code....

```
if let date = userInfoDic.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.date") as? Any {
let dateString = String(describing: date)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(date)
} }
```

Comment: "if let date = userInfoDic.value(forKey: "gcm.notification.date") as? Any"

This always will be true.

Comment: U can use this as u want